# ¿Por qué me da un string undefined?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo una función que obtiene el nombre de un rango dependiendo de una facción en la base de datos

```
function nombreRango(rango, org){
    const dataOrg = {
        memberRange: rango,
        memberOrg: org
    };
    $.post('/cargarDatos.php', dataOrg, function (response) {
        rangoArray = JSON.parse(response);
        rangoName = rangoArray[0].rangoName;
        console.log(nombreRango);
        return rangoName;
    })
}
```

Al momento de hacer `console.log(nombreRango);` me muestra el nombre del rango correctamente, pero al hacer `return nombreRango;` se inserta en la tabla con el texto "`undefined`".

Este es el backend

```
        $memberRange = $_POST['memberRange'];
        $memberOrg = $_POST['memberOrg'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Nombre = '$memberOrg'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($result !== false) {
            $value = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $rangoString = "Rango" . $memberRange;
            $datos[] = array(
                'rangoName' => $value[$rangoString],
                'datoX' => 'X'
            );
            $jsonstring = json_encode($datos);
            echo $jsonstring;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al hacer una llamada a servidor asíncrona, "nos salimos" del flujo de ejecución mientras el hilo principal sigue adelante. Ten en cuenta que esa función asíncrona que "se sale" del flujo puede tardar n segundos y en ese tiempo, el hilo principal ha seguido su flujo. Por lo tanto, y visto de esta manera, es normal que no se pueda retornar cuando una función ejecuta código asíncrono.

En tu caso, para poder manejar el valor de `rangoName` podrías, por ejemplo, crear otra función que implemente la lógica que desees:

```
function nombreRango(rango, org){
    const dataOrg = {
        memberRange: rango,
        memberOrg: org
    };
    $.post('/cargarDatos.php', dataOrg, function (response) {
        rangoArray = JSON.parse(response);
        rangoName = rangoArray[0].rangoName;
        console.log(rangoName);
        DoSomethingRangoName(rangoName);
    })
}

function DoSomethingRangoName(rangoName) {
    // DoSomething
}
```

Comment: zeross, la ídea de la función es obtener el nombre del rango (almacenado en la base de datos) y con esto llenar una tabla con esto. Por eso necesito el `return` ¿Existe alguna alternativa?

Comment: Pues la idea es que te crees una función, llamemosla por ejemplo `llenarTabla()`, en la que, recibiendo el parámetro `rangoName`, llenes la tabla

Answer (score 0):

Una función devuelve undefined si no se ha devuelto un valor. En la función nombreRango, debes tener un **return** en su cuerpo.

Comment: La función tiene su `return` intenté poniéndolo fuera del `$.post` e igual me da undefined, deje uno dentro y otro fuera y me da vacío.

Comment: Por favor no coloques código como imagen, pégalo como texto, seleccionalo y presiona `ctrl + k` para darle formato

Answer (score 0):

Investigando me di cuenta que tenía que cambiar `$.post` por `$.ajax` y la función quedó de este modo

```
const dataOrg = {
    memberRange: rango,
    memberOrg: org,
    verRango : "verRango"
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/CargarDatos.php',
    data: dataOrg,
    success: function (response) {
        rangoArray = JSON.parse(response);
        rangoName = rangoArray[0].rangoName;
    }, 
    async: false
    })
return rangoName;
```

Comment: Ten cuidado. Te funciona porque te estás cargando la asincronía. Según jQuery está desaconsejado.

Comment: Según jQuery y según cualquier navegador: te mostrará un warning durante la ejecución

Comment: Usé respuesta de zeross, gracias por sus comentarios. Dejaré la respuesta por si alguien llega a tener este error y opta por mi opción, sepa por sus comentarios que no es recomendable. Muchas gracias a ambos.